# update database with clicked off of database

Tags: javascript, php

I am using this PHP code to display data from a database in a text area and then when updated, once the user clicks off the text area it updates the data in the database

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from controldata where field = :field ");
$stmt->execute(array(':field' => 'notice_board'));
$result = $stmt->fetch();
?>
<textarea id="notice_board_textarea" data-id="notice_board" rows="8"><?php echo stripslashes(strip_tags($result["value"])); ?></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#notice_board_textarea').on('blur', function () { // don't forget # to select by id
    var id = $(this).data('id'); // Get the id-data-attribute
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/updatenoticeboard.php",
        data: {
            notes: val, // value of the textarea we are hooking the blur-event to
            itemId: id,  // Id of the item stored on the data-id
            update_notice_board:"yes"
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

the updatenoticeboard.php page has the query on to update the database and also should echo some text, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything

is there something wrong with the javascript?

Comment: Show us your relevant PHP in updatenoticeboard.php?

Comment: Since you are using AJAX, you shouldn't expect updatenoticeboard.php to be able to echo any text.   Anything that is echoed by the php file can only be processed by the AJAX response handler.

Answer (score 0):

Do these things:

1. At the server end echo the content in html format (just the content, what you intend to show in textarea and nothing like - body, head, div etc.. NO.
2. At the time of ajax request write success function (see jquery docs to get what is success and error function in ajax request) and in that do like this..

success: function(response){

`#("#id_of_textarea").val(response.html); //use response.text if you are using text as`

```
datatype
}
```

1. Go through ajax request documentation. You didn't made proper request - put suitable values for options like -

   cache: false,
   dataType: text, //or text/html or json.. . whatever.. you use response.text for text and so on..

etc.. just see the docs for once..